# TSQL Least number of appearances

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My question is that I want to find the "Balie" with the least number of "Maatschappijen" booked on it. So far I got this query wich displays all "Balies" and all the "Maatschappijen" with them. The wanted result is one "balienummer" record with the least number of "maatschappijen" booked on it.

Query

```
SELECT [Balie].[balienummer], [IncheckenBijMaatschappij].[balienummer],  [IncheckenBijMaatschappij].[maatschappijcode]
FROM [Balie]
JOIN [IncheckenBijMaatschappij]
ON [Balie].[balienummer] = [IncheckenBijMaatschappij].[balienummer]
```

Query result

```
balienummer balienummer maatschappijcode
1           1           BA
1           1           TR
2           2           AF
2           2           NZ
3           3           KL
4           4           KL
```

LRS: https://www.dropbox.com/s/f2l9a874d5witpt/LRS_CasusGelreAirport.pdf

Comment: have you tried MIN([Balie].[balienummer]) ?

Comment: Yes, that's not working. Because it selects the lowest balienummer. Thanks for thinking tho!

Comment: Least number of distinct maatschappijcode or total ( could BA and TR be duplicated? for the same balie?)

Comment: There could be more "balies" to one or multiple "maatschappijen"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT [Balie].[balienummer],  count([IncheckenBijMaatschappij].[maatschappijcode])
FROM [Balie]
JOIN [IncheckenBijMaatschappij]
ON [Balie].[balienummer] = [IncheckenBijMaatschappij].[balienummer]
GROUP BY [Balie].[balienummer]
ORDER BY count([IncheckenBijMaatschappij].[maatschappijcode])
```

First record should be your answer.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be correct. But is there any way to only limit to first result? LIMIT seems not to work?

Comment: Maybe try 'SELECT TOP 1...'

Comment: Ah, usually i'm working with MYSQL. Thanks! Thankyou very much!